# Ошибка Integer.parseInt при чтении из файла

Tags: java

Ошибка Integer.parseInt при чтении из файла txt.txt.
В файле строка: "2 4 6". 
Выдает ошибку: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2"

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/txt.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String[] parts = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                for (String str : parts)
                    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
            }
            fr.close();
            for (Integer i : intList)
                System.out.println(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: приложите stacktrace

Comment: может что-то non-printable вклинилось. попробуйте `Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", ""))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fileReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) считывает сразу всю строку. Если файл выглядит следующим образом

```
 1 2 3 4 12 34
 3 4 5 34 23 23
```

То readLine() вернет вам `1 2 3 4 12 34`

Поэтому вам необходимо после чтения разделить символы по пробелам.

```
while (fileReader.ready()){ 
     for (String number : fileReader.readLine().split(" ")){
            int i = Integer.parseInt(number);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                list.add(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: и все равно тоже самое Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12"

Comment: не могли бы приложить содержимое файла в тело вопроса, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/805829/edit)?

Comment: внес изменения в тело

Comment: и ошибка точно такая же `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12"` ? приложите модержимое файла к телу, пожалуйста

Comment: @YanS число 12 - оно последние (или единственное) в строке?

Comment: @newman условия уточнил в теле вопроса

Comment: @SeniorPomidor добавил тело, посмотрите. вы это имеете в виду? или пожалуйста подскажите как его добавить.